# Fixing burnt epoxy? Redo the whole table or can do a patch?

Tags: epoxy

So I guess I got a little aggressive with the heat gun and some epoxy burned in a small section of the table. This was supposed to be the seal coat, but seemed pretty thick for that (used the calculator on mfgr website for amount of epoxy to use for seal coat).  Anyway, seemed like one area had more bubbles and so I kinda sat there for a while and then it REALLY started bubbling and then smoking.

Any thoughts on fixing?  Is it possible to sand down the one area and then try and blend it with the existing epoxy?  If so, I'd also be worried about sanding the stain that I did prior to the pour.

[image: Close up of burnt epoxy]
[image: Further back from burnt epoxy]

Comment: This is much thicker than I'd have expected a 'seal coat' to look, but that's very much in your favour! It should be possible to locally sand that area flat without risking sanding through. However, there is no guarantee you'll be able to erase all sign of these bubbles so I'd go into it expecting to see a tiny bit of 'silvering' in the foamed spot and maybe the retention of a few bubbles when the flood coat goes on. But I think it'll be plenty thick enough to deal with the surface irregularities and result in a level surface at the end.

Comment: What's the suggested recoat time for this epoxy? Do the instructions say anything about what to do if you exceed this window?

Comment: Yeah, I was not expecting this seal coat to be so thick.  I'm wondering if it may have made it harder for gas to escape?  So, the recommended recoat time was 4 hours and if after that then it recommends scuff sanding at 320 so the flood coat will adhere.  Is it okay to sand it at 80 or should I start a little higher like 180?  I thought many people bring it all the way up to 800-1000, is that helpful prior to flood coat or is that only for after the flood coat, ending with buffing in a polishing compound?

Comment: With a seal coat this thick, is a flood coat even necessary (say I didn't mess it up, why even do another coat)?  For 18.74 sq ft entered into the calculator, the result gave 
60 oz for the seal coat and 224 oz for a flood coat.  I even reduced the seal coat by 10% since I didn't have enough epoxy for both those amounts.  Given how thick the seal coat was, should I just mix a flood coat closer to the seal coat amount?  Not sure what I gain with that much more epoxy, other than maybe better self leveling?

Comment: Yeah I just wanted to check they do recommend sanding/scuffing after the default recoat time — realise that will make scratches all over the surface that the next coat will completely cover, gives you some idea of what the epoxy will naturally take care of. [IME a thick coat of epoxy will cover *any* amount of scratches.] Re. starting sanding at a coarse grit, it might be better to ignore the general rules of sanding because you want to be so careful not to sand through here. So which normally it might be suggested you start sanding at 80 for efficiency, for this 150/180 sounds just right.

Comment: *"I thought many people bring it all the way up to 800-1000"* Sanding up to those grits should be confined exclusively to when you're flatting and then polishing that surface, like going for a 'piano finish' like you might want on a boardroom table. There's absolutely no reason to sand to those grits otherwise. General point: some people these days routinely sand way higher than they need to, it's just one of many things that aren't done the way they used to when formal training was more common. Now people wing it a lot more, go with their gut/what worked for them once (without being sure why)

Comment: ok, thanks for the advise, I'll try tackle this when i get back next month!